# Can Anyone Recommend a Tool for Map Building?

Tags: geography, worldbuilding-resources, map-making

I would like to make a map for black & white inclusion in a book. I'd like to have lines of latitude and longitude, and be able to drop cities.

Could anyone recommend a good map building tool that can be exported to 2D black & white?

Comment: The answer there is either a paint application or one application that might be nice, but looks to run on Windows only. The last answer there had some tools to follow-up with. That might be the answer, but I would like to check.

Comment: Well here is an answer, because after some digging I found a lot more map tools :

Comment: Well here is an answer, because after some digging I found a lot more map tools :
* For maps inspired by real world locations National Geographic offers an interactive map maker - https://www.nationalgeographic.org/mapmaker-interactive/
* Google MyMaps also offers a blank look at parts of the Earth that you can add your own points and labels to - https://www.google.com/maps/about/mymaps/
* Scribble Maps is another free tool like Google MyMaps - https://www.scribblemaps.com/create
* Smart Drawn is an online tool for map making for $9.95/month - https://www.smartdraw.com/map/map-maker.htm